# Magento2 - observer equivalent to admin_user_save_before

Tags: magento2, event-observer, extensions

I'm rewriting a home-grown M1 extension for M2. The M1 extension utilises an observer on the admin_user_save_before event.

I can't find any equivalent event for Magento2 - is there something I'm missing?

Comment: There must be some problem with you code, as I'm using the same event in M2.

Comment: admin_user_save_before ? I can't see anywhere where that is fired.

Answer (score 1):

These are all Magento 2 Admin User Events:

**1) backend_auth_user_login_success**

> app/code/Magento/Backend/Model/Auth.php

```
$this->_eventManager->dispatch(
    'backend_auth_user_login_success',
    ['user' => $this->getCredentialStorage()]);
```

**2) backend_auth_user_login_failed**

> app/code/Magento/Backend/Model/Auth.php

```
$this->_eventManager->dispatch(
    'backend_auth_user_login_failed',
    ['user_name' => $username, 'exception' => $e]);
```

**3) backend_auth_user_login_failed**

> app/code/Magento/Backend/Model/Auth.php

```
$this->_eventManager->dispatch(
    'backend_auth_user_login_failed',
    ['user_name' => $username, 'exception' => $e]);
```

**4) permissions_role_html_before**

> app/code/Magento/User/Block/Role.php

```
$this->_eventManager->dispatch('permissions_role_html_before', ['block' => $this]);
```

**5) admin_permissions_role_prepare_save**

> app/code/Magento/User/Controller/Adminhtml/User/Role/SaveRole.php

```
$this->_eventManager->dispatch(
    'admin_permissions_role_prepare_save',
    ['object' => $role, 'request' => $this->getRequest()]);
```

**6) admin_user_authenticate_before**

> app/code/Magento/User/Model/User.php

```
$this->_eventManager->dispatch(
    'admin_user_authenticate_before',
    ['username' => $username, 'user' => $this]);
```

**7) admin_user_authenticate_after**

> app/code/Magento/User/Model/User.php

```
$this->_eventManager->dispatch(
    'admin_user_authenticate_after',
    ['username' => $username, 'password' => $password, 'user' => $this, 'result' => $result]);
```

Comment: permissions_role_html_before looks like what I'm looking for! Thanks :)

Comment: Hmmm, looking at this again, it seems that actually hooks in to the saving of a permission group rather than a user itself.